# Как сделать смену направления текста?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет. Хотел бы спросить у знатоков, может быть кто делал подобное: как сделать смену направления текста с каждой новой строки. Полувизуальный пример:

текст слева-направо
текст справа-налево
текст слева-направо
текст справа-налево.. и т.д.

Перенос - не абзац (`<br>`), а обычный word-wrap. Я так понимаю, меня интересует смена значений с ltr на rtl и наоборот каждую новую строку.

В примере ниже я сделал это при помощи параграфов и ксса. В моём случае мне нужно, чтобы текст переносился после word-wrap и будучи исключительно в одном параграфе, диве и т.д.

```css
.ltr {
  direction: ltr;
  }
.rtl {
  direction: rtl;
  }
```

```html
<p class="ltr">Some text ltr</p>
<p class="rtl">ltr txet emoS</p>
<p class="ltr">Some text ltr</p>
<p class="rtl">ltr txet emoS</p>
<p class="ltr">Some text ltr</p>
<p class="rtl">ltr txet emoS</p>
```

Comment: Какое практическое применение этому? Мне кажется что без оборачивания каждой строки в тег не обойдетесь.

Comment: Блин, хреново. Да вот делаю сайт, хотят чтобы текст читался именно так, обосновывая это тем, что он так лучше воспринимается

Comment: Хм. Странное дело. Тысячелетиями текст нормально воспринимался с одним направлением, а тут, внезапно, лучше будет восприниматься если каждая строка по-своему :\ Кстати в вашем примере не понятно как именно вы хотите сделать. Должно меняться выравнивание или порядок букв должен меняться или и то и другое?

Comment: Психологи видят иначе. Насколько я понял, меня интересует смена значения ltr на rtl и наоборот каждую новую строчку.

Comment: как это в итоге должно выглядеть? _текст слева-направо_ в примере ничем не отличается от _текст справа-налево_

Comment: Добавил пример с jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать как-то так (по идее, можно ускорить, прикидывая, сколько слов влезет в строку и добавляя сразу несколько):

```js
function wrap(element){
  var text = element.getAttribute('data-original');
  if (!text){
    text = element.textContent.trim();
    element.setAttribute('data-original', text);
  }
  
  var words = text.split(/\s+/);
  var result = '', line = '', reverseLine = false;
  
  element.innerHTML = 'a';
  var height = element.offsetHeight;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
    var candidate = line + ' ' + words[i];    
    element.innerHTML = result + candidate;
    if (element.offsetHeight > height){
      height = element.offsetHeight;
      result += '<div>' + line + '</div>';
      line = words[i];
    } else {
      line = candidate;
    }
  }
  
  if (line) result += '<div>' + line + '</div>';
  element.innerHTML = result;
}

function wrapAll(){
  console.time('wrapAll()');
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.weird-word-wrapping'), wrap);
  console.timeEnd('wrapAll()');
}

wrapAll();
window.onresize = wrapAll;
```

```css
.weird-word-wrapping div:nth-child(2n) {
  direction: rtl;
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="weird-word-wrapping">Многие думают, что Lorem Ipsum - взятый с потолка псевдо-латинский набор слов, но это не совсем так. Его корни уходят в один фрагмент классической латыни 45 года н.э., то есть более двух тысячелетий назад. Ричард МакКлинток, профессор латыни из колледжа Hampden-Sydney, штат Вирджиния, взял одно из самых странных слов в Lorem Ipsum, "consectetur", и занялся его поисками в классической латинской литературе. В результате он нашёл неоспоримый первоисточник Lorem Ipsum в разделах 1.10.32 и 1.10.33 книги "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" ("О пределах добра и зла"), написанной Цицероном в 45 году н.э. Этот трактат по теории этики был очень популярен в эпоху Возрождения. Первая строка Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", происходит от одной из строк в разделе 1.10.32</div>
```

Без ручного переноса, насколько я понимаю, сделать не выйдет.

Comment: Это просто невероятно! Большое спасибо за помощь!!!